# Singleton Dependencies not getting disposed when closing application with X button

Tags: .net, dependency-injection

I have a dependency that must be closed before exiting my web app for proper use.
So far from what I've noticed singleton dependencies are getting disposed when exiting the web app with ctrl+c but not when closing with X button of the console.
Is there a workaround to make the app dispose dependencies when closing the app with X button ?

I'm running On .Net 6

EDIT:
some code to demonstrate what I'm saying.

Program.cs :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


builder.Services.AddSingleton<SomeDependency>((_)=>new SomeDependency());

var app = builder.Build();

//just so the dependency is instanciated
app.Services.GetService<SomeDependency>();

app.Run();
```

SomeDependency.cs

```
public class SomeDependency : IDisposable
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
        File.Delete("test.txt");
        }
    }
```

Using the following example, test.txt file is deleted when using ctrl+c, but it is not when closing with X button of the console.

EDIT:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += CurrentDomain_ProcessExit;

void CurrentDomain_ProcessExit(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // disposing my dependencies here
}
```

Now closing with X button correctly disposes all dependencies

Comment: What do you mean by "closing with X button of the console" while running a web application? Do you mean when the user closes their browser? A web application doesn't shut down when a user closes the browser.

Comment: This has nothing to do with dependency injection. Web sites don't run from consoles. They run either as separate services, daemons or in the case of IIS and NGINX, hosted sites. You're confusing closing the console with closing the IIS site or Kestrel process. How did you start your web app? Did you use `dotnet run`? Something else? Is the web app configured to run under IIS or standalone?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it does dispose the dependencies when using ctrl+c on the console though, I directly run using builded executable file and the web app is configured to run standalone.

Comment: No, it disposes them when the application terminates. If the application doesn't terminate, nothing is disposed.  You still haven't explained what the application does or how it's hosted, or how you started it. `From the command line` doesn't say anything. Did you call `dotnet run` in your project folder? Directly called the executable in `bin/Release`? I suspect you created a worker service though, which *does* listen for the Ctrl+C keystroke and terminates the application.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I double click the executable file in bin/release

Comment: In that case the web app is started by Windows Explorer, not the console. I suspect you'll find an orphaned instance of your application in Task Manager

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes that's indeed the case but is there any workaround to this ?

Comment: Yes, close the application. What you describe is a misunderstanding how processes work in general, not a problem with .NET or web sites. I repeat, web sites either run in the background, as services or daemons, or hosted by web servers like IIS and NGINX. They don't run from consoles or get started by double-clicking

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the application is correctly getting closed, request won't pass anymore after so it is correctly closed.

Comment: If you see an orphaned process, it's not. In any case, you're asking people to simply guess what could be wrong, with no indication that anything is wrong to begin with. When a process terminates *every* resource it held is released by the OS itself. There's no if or but about this.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks but I found a workaround by setting AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit event and disposing my dependencies inside

Comment: A workaround to what? You still haven't described a problem. It seems that your actual question is why your `Dispose` isn't running the way you thought it would, not that singletons aren't disposed.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No Dispose is **not getting called** at all

Comment: Post your code so people can help you then. It's obvious this has nothing to do with resource disposal or closing connections, because those get closed by the operating system. Perhaps your `Dispose` is trying to do something that takes so much time the runtime kills it anyway. Or perhaps you have a worker service that doesn't listen to the cancellation token. Others don't have such problems, so it's something in the code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm gonna post some code but I mean the same app correctly disposes everything when using ctrl+c to close so I guess my code is fine.

Comment: You didn't post any code yet. What you posted contains nothing useful. If your code run the same way every other .NET Core web app does you wouldn't have to handle `ProcessExit`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I posted some code to demonstrate what I'm saying.